# Many-to-many join table with additional field in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `Products` and `Orders`, inside my Flask-SqlAlchemy setup, and they are linked so an order can have several products:

```
class Products(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ....

class Orders(db.Model):
    guid = db.Column(db.String(36), default=generate_uuid, primary_key=True)
    products = db.relationship(
        "Products", secondary=order_products_table, backref="orders")
    ....
```

linked via:

```
order_products_table = db.Table("order_products_table",
    db.Column('orders_guid', db.String(36), db.ForeignKey('orders.guid')),
    db.Column('products_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id'))
    # db.Column('license', dbString(36))
)
```

For my purposes, each product in an order will receive a unique license string, which logically should be added to the `order_products_table` rows of each product in an order.

How do I declare this third `license` column on the join table `order_products_table` so it gets populated it as I insert an Order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've since found the documentation for the [Association Object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) from the SQLAlchemy docs, which allows for exactly this expansion to the join table.

**Updated setup:**

```
# Instead of a table, provide a model for the JOIN table with additional fields 
# and explicit keys and back_populates:
class OrderProducts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'order_products_table'
    orders_guid = db.Column(db.String(36), db.ForeignKey(
        'orders.guid'), primary_key=True)
    products_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'products.id'), primary_key=True)

    order = db.relationship("Orders", back_populates="products")
    products = db.relationship("Products", back_populates="order")

    licenses = db.Column(db.String(36), nullable=False)

class Products(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order = db.relationship(OrderProducts, back_populates="order")
    ....

class Orders(db.Model):
    guid = db.Column(db.String(36), default=generate_uuid, primary_key=True)
    products = db.relationship(OrderProducts, back_populates="products")
    ....
```

What is really tricky (but also shown on the documentation page), is how you insert the data. In my case it goes something like this:

```
o = Orders(...) # insert other data
for id in products:
    # Create OrderProducts join rows with the extra data, e.g. licenses
    join = OrderProducts(licenses="Foo")
    # To the JOIN add the products 
    join.products = Products.query.get(id)
    # Add the populated JOIN as the Order products
    o.products.append(join)

# Finally commit to database
db.session.add(o)
db.session.commit()
```

I was at first trying to populate the Order.products (or `o.products` in the example code) directly, which will give you an error about using a Products class when it expects a OrderProducts class.

I also struggled with the whole field naming and referencing of the `back_populates`. Again, the example above and on the docs show this. Note the pluralization is entirely to do with how you want your fields named.